# Odd behavior of ODE in Scilab: equation dy/dx=A is not solved properly

Tags: line, ode, scilab

I am still learning Scilab (5.5.2), so I am writing and running test codes to familiarize myself with the software.

To test the numerical differential equation solver, I started easy from the equation *dy/dx = A*, which has as solution *y = Ax+c* (line equation).

This is the code I wrote:

```
// Function y = A*x+1
function ydot=fn(x, A)
    ydot=A
endfunction
A=2;
//Initial conditions
x0=0;
y0=A*x0+1;
//Numerical Solution
x=[0:5];
y= ode(y0,x0,x,fn);
//Analytical solution
y2 = A*x+1;
clf(); plot(x, y); plot(x, y2, '-k');
//End
```

And these are the unexpected results:

> y = 1.    2.7182824    7.3890581    20.085545    54.598182
>   148.41327
>
> y2 = 1.    3.    5.    7.    9.    11.

It appears that *y = e^x*. Can someone explain what is going wrong, or what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just renaming the variables does not change how they are used internally by the ODE solver. Since that solver expects a function with arguments `time,state` it will interpret the provided function that way.

Renaming the variables back, what you programmed is equivalent to

```
function ydot=fn(t,y)
    ydot = y
endfunction
```

which indeed has the exponential function as solution.

From the [manual](https://www.scilab.org/product/man/ode.html) you can see that the way to include parameters is to pass the function as a list,

> The f argument can also be a list with the following structure: `lst=list(realf,u1,u2,...un)` where `realf` is a Scilab function with syntax: `ydot = f(t,y,u1,u2,...,un)`

```
function ydot=fn(t,y,A)
    ydot = A
endfunction

y= ode(y0,x0,x,list(fn,A));
```

Comment: I appreciate that, I will test the code you suggest.

Comment: And after  quite a while, how to make it work if A is a vector?

Comment: Did you try it? It should not matter what object you pass in the parameter list.

Comment: With the correct code you suggested, and  A = ones(1:10), what I get is an error message, error 98.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve, what your function is with these mulitiple parameters. I think the comment space is too short and not appropriate. Please open a new question with details, expected behavior vs. observed or error message, and perhaps a link to this question.